# Getting an error while converting my dataset in TFrecord format for running Deeplabs in colab

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, tfrecord, deeplab

I am trying to run Deeplabs on my custom dataset in Colab.
And i want to convert my dataset into TFRecord format but when i am running the build_voc2012_data.py file i am getting an error. Could someone tell me why i am getting it and how to get rid of it?

```
!python build_voc2012_data.py \
--image_folder="./skin_lesion/JPEGImages" \
--semantic_segmentation_folder="./skin_lesion/SegmentationClass" \
--list_folder="./skin_lesion/ImageSets/Segmentation" \
--image_format="jpg" \
--output_dir="./tfrecord"
```

```
2020-12-28 06:34:25.620292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-28 06:34:28.833301: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-12-28 06:34:28.866544: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-12-28 06:34:28.929087: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2020-12-28 06:34:28.929146: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (a0267f2cdac9): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-12-28 06:34:28.929781: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-12-28 06:34:28.933455: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Processing trainTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_voc2012_data.py", line 147, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "build_voc2012_data.py", line 143, in main
    _convert_dataset(dataset_split)
  File "build_voc2012_data.py", line 112, in _convert_dataset
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename) as tfrecord_writer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py", line 299, in __init__
    compat.as_bytes(path), options._as_record_writer_options())
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ./tfrecord/train-00000-of-00004.tfrecord; No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says it's the issue with `No such file or directory` for tfrecord output directory.
You can mention the absolute path in `output_dir`, in colab you can right click on the folder and `copy path` to get the absolute path of the directory.